# Changing tab color on Android works partially

Tags: android, tabs

I've been trying to change tab colors of my android app. But i can't get it done. I've copied all the needed images and repainted them in Photoshop. But this is all i get.

[image]

What i first did was copy the `tab_indicator.xml` from the `drawable` folder in `android-sdk\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable`.

Then i copied all the images that are referenced in that xml file to my own `drawable-hdpi` folder. I copied those image from the `android-sdk\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-hdpi` folder.

I re-painted the `tab_unselected.png` file like this:

Orignal file (tab_unselected.9.png):
[image]

New file:
[image]

But as you can see in the top screenshot, only the borders are colored. The tab itself just remains black when unselected.

What do i have to do to style that tab **without** the use of any Java code. I don't mind adding any XML files or editting .png files.

---

BTW, i added a custom `TabHost` xml file in my `layout` folder and added `android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator"` to the `TabWidget` tag.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna change only tab color you not required to use png files. Take a look here, hope it will be helpfull http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136